# JQuery function called on page load

Tags: jquery, django

I just started to work with JQuery and this is starting to drive me nuts.
The code is for a Django project.

#### Template

```
{% extends "core/base.html" %}
{% load url from future %}


{% block title %}Register Company{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#country_subdivision").hide();
                $("#address").hide();
                $("#postal_code").hide();
                $("#city").hide();

                var states;
                $("#id_company_country").change(function () {
                    var country = $("#id_company_country").val();
                    states = $.get("{% url 'get_country_subdivisions' 1 %}", function (data, status) {

                    });
                    alert(states);
                    $("#id_company_country_subdivision").empty();
                    $("#country_subdivision").show();

                    $(JSON.parse(states.country_subdivisions)).map(function () {
                        return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.label);
                    }).appendTo('#id_company_country_subdivision');
                });

                $("#id_company_country_subdivision").change(function () {
                    $("#address").show();
                    $("#postal_code").show();
                    $("#city").show();
                });
            })
        </script>
        <h1>Registration form</h1>
        <form class="ci-form" action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if error_message %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error_message }}</div>
            {% endif %}
            <h2>Company information</h2>
            <div><span><label
                    for="{{ form.company_name.id_for_label }}">{{ form.company_name.label }} </label>{{ form.company_name }}{{ form.company_name.error }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.company_name.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <br/>
            <div><span><label for="{{ form.company_phone.id_for_label }}">{{ form.company_phone.label }} </label>{{ form.company_phone }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.company_phone.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div><span><label for="{{ form.company_fax.id_for_label }}">{{ form.company_fax.label }} </label>{{ form.company_fax }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.company_fax.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <br/>
            <div><span><label for="{{ form.company_email.id_for_label }}">{{ form.company_email.label }} </label>{{ form.company_email }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.company_email.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div><span><label for="{{ form.company_website.id_for_label }}">{{ form.company_website.label }} </label>{{ form.company_website }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.company_website.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <br/>
            <div id="country"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.company_country.id_for_label }}">{{ form.company_country.label }} </label>{{ form.company_country }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.company_country.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div id="country_subdivision"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.company_country_subdivision.id_for_label }}">{{ form.company_country_subdivision.label }} </label>{{ form.company_country_subdivision }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.company_country_subdivision.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div id="address"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.company_address.id_for_label }}">{{ form.company_address.label }} </label>{{ form.company_address }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.company_address.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div id="postal_code"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.company_postal_code.id_for_label }}">{{ form.company_postal_code.label }} </label>{{ form.company_postal_code }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.company_postal_code.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div id="city"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.company_city.id_for_label }}">{{ form.company_city.label }} </label>{{ form.company_city }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.company_city.errors.as_text }}</span></div>

            <h2 id="user_informatino">User information</h2>
            <div id="username"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.user_username.id_for_label }}">{{ form.user_username.label }} </label>{{ form.user_username }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.user_username.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div id="pwd"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.user_password.id_for_label }}">{{ form.user_password.label }} </label>{{ form.user_password }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.user_password.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div id="pwd2"><label for="{{ form.user_password_2.id_for_label }}">{{ form.user_password_2.label }} </label>{{ form.user_password_2 }}
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.user_password_2.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <br/>
            <div id="first_name"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.user_first_name.id_for_label }}">{{ form.user_first_name.label }} </label>{{ form.user_first_name }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.user_first_name.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div id="initials"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.user_initials.id_for_label }}">{{ form.user_initials.label }} </label>{{ form.user_initials }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.user_initials.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div id="last_name"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.user_last_name.id_for_label }}">{{ form.user_last_name.label }} </label>{{ form.user_last_name }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.user_last_name.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div id="gender"><span><label for="{{ form.user_gender.id_for_label }}">{{ form.user_gender.label }} </label>{{ form.user_gender }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.user_gender.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <br/>
            <div id="user_phone"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.user_phone.id_for_label }}">{{ form.user_phone.label }} </label>{{ form.user_phone }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.user_phone.errors.as_text }}</span></div>
            <div id="user_email"><span><label
                    for="{{ form.user_email.id_for_label }}">{{ form.user_email.label }} </label>{{ form.user_email }}</span>
                <span class="ci-inline-error">{{ form.user_email.errors.as_text }}</span></div>

            <input type="submit" class="ci-button margin-bottom-20" value="Register >>">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

#### Url

```
url(r'^get_country_subdivisions/(?P<country_id>\d*)/$', get_country_subdivisions_for_country, name="get_country_subdivisions")
```

#### Method for getting subdivisions

```
def get_country_subdivisions_for_country(request, country_id):
    if country_id:
        country_subdivisions = CountrySubdivision.objects.filter(country_id=country_id)
        if len(country_subdivisions):
            country_subdivisions = [{"value": csd.id, "label": csd.name} for csd in country_subdivisions]
            country_subdivisions = json.dumps({"country_subdivisions": country_subdivisions})

        return HttpResponse(country_subdivisions)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps("{}"))
```

There are a couple of things happening here:

#### Function runs on page load

It seems the function inside `$("#id_company_country").change` is running when the page is loaded and I the error below.

I figured I had to be sure so I check the country value and set it to a default if it is null or empty twice. Once inside the function and once outside the function.

```
if (country == null) {
    country = 31;
}
```

For the comparison I have tried the operators `=`, `==`, reversed `!=`, `!==` and the values `null`, `''` and "". None of them worked.

Because I still get this error I guess the function is being called when I open the website.

```
Reverse for 'get_country_subdivisions' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'country_id': ''}' not found.
```

#### Return value

For testing purpuses I hardcoded the country to 1 inside the get function

```
$.getJSON("{% url 'get_country_subdivisions' country_id=1 %}", function(data, status) {
    alert(status)
});
```

When I do this I do get the alert box with the value of the selected country, so that seems to work. 
But when I get the response it looks like this (From Google Chrome console):

```
GET
http://localhost:8012/contact_management/get_country_subdivisions/1/[%22Ala…ashington%22,%20%22West%20Virginia%22,%20%22Wisconsin%22,%20%22Wyoming%22] 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Which obviously is not the correct url, but I would expect the values to be in the data parameter.

What obvious things am I missing here?

Comment: `country_id=1` in `{% url %}` is invalid. I guess it will be ok just to pass the value of the argument; i.e. `{% url 'get_country_subdivisions' 1 %}` (or '1').

Comment: Can you show us the full HTML code generated when loading the page and/or the full template, it looks like there's something missing...

Comment: @raphv I have added the full template, updated the function and the url

Comment: The $.get function in jQuery is asynchronous and doesn't return its results, so the rest of the code will not be able to access the results. Instead, you should put all the code below in the callback, where the subdivisions will be in your "data" variable.